# Remote SSH connection hangs at "Downloading vscode server step" after updating VScode to 1.82.0 version

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, remote-access, remote-server, vscode-remote

I am trying to connect to Remote SSH through Remote-SSH extension, however it hangs at "Downloading VSCode Server" step for a long time after updating the vscode release. Please find the logs for the same as below

```
[17:55:58.394] Remote server is listening on port 44281
[17:55:58.394] Parsed server configuration: {"serverConfiguration":{"remoteListeningOn":{"port":44281},"osReleaseId":"ol","arch":"x86_64","sshAuthSock":"","display":"","tmpDir":"/run/user/1663455","platform":"linux"},"serverStartTime":70,"installUnpackCode":""}
[17:55:58.395] Persisting server connection details to /Users/skatpara/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-5d30b538-8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314-0.106.1/data.json
[17:55:58.398] Starting forwarding server. local port 49696 -> socksPort 49694 -> remotePort 44281
[17:55:58.398] Forwarding server listening on port 49696
[17:55:58.398] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[17:55:58.400] Tunneled port 44281 to local port 49696
[17:55:58.400] Resolved "ssh-remote+node" to "port 49696"
[17:55:58.402] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+node
[17:55:58.402] Resolving exec server at port 49696
[17:55:58.414] [Forwarding server port 49696] Got connection 0
[17:55:58.415] [Forwarding server port 49696] Got connection 1
[17:55:59.362] Exec server for ssh-remote+node created and cached
[17:55:59.369] ------




[17:55:59.693] [server] Checking /home/uname/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314/log.txt and /home/uname/.vscode-server/cli/servers/Stable-8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314/pid.txt for a running server...
[17:55:59.735] [server] Installing and setting up Visual Studio Code Server...
```

I expect to resolve the issue and be able to connect to remote server through vscode Remote-SSH extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug in version 0.106.1 of the Remote SSH extension used with VS Code 1.82: [[Remote-SSH Bug]: Remote-SSH 0.106.1 gets stuck downloading the server
#8926](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8926)

The [suggested workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8926#issuecomment-1710915484) for version 0.106.1 is to set `"remote.SSH.useExecServer": false`. It is [disabled by default in version 0.106.2](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8926#issuecomment-1712360113). The default will be changed back to `true` when the bug is fixed- [perhaps in the next stable VS Code release](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8926#issuecomment-1712545639).

Before 0.106.2 was released, other users used other workarounds such as [downgrading/rolling-back the extension to version `0.102.0`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8926#issuecomment-1710952576), [downloading and extracting the server files manually](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8926#issuecomment-1711090630), [downgrading VS Code to 1.81](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8926#issuecomment-1711799004).

Answer (score 4):

The newest VSCode version does not play nice with the most recent version of the "Remote SSH" extension due to a bug. It is being tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/8926) though it seems like it mostly ocurrs when the remote machine you're connecting to does not have an internet connection.
While this is being fixed you could try

1. setting `remote.SSH.useExecServer": false` in `settings.json` or toggle the "Use Exec Server" checkbox in the settings

or

2. Downgrade VSCode and the "Remote SSH" extension to an older version

Comment: I downgraded the extension only, and after closing all my connections opened, it works.